# Check index fragmentation without using analyze index command?

Tags: oracle, index-tuning

I've researched and a lot of scripts need to use `analyze index` command first. Is there some other way to check index fragmentation without populate those columns in `index_stats` table? some alternative script?

Edit: the reason I am asking it's because `analyze index validate structure` lock the table for DML operations.

Answer (score 1):

What is the issue with the `analyze` command?

Is it space? Oracle *already* collects all the metadata that `analyze` generates; running the command only updates that metadata based on the current state of the index.

Or is it time/performance? You can check for issues with the index with a SQL query, but for *specific* analysis of any problems you still need to run `analyze`. From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/admin/managing-schema-objects.html#GUID-F25B8EBF-670E-44C9-B399-3AE1D521D065):

> **18.2.4 Cross Validation of a Table and an Index with a Query**
>
> In some cases, an ANALYZE statement takes an inordinate amount of time
> to complete. In these cases, you can use a SQL query to validate an
> index.
>
> If the query determines that there is an inconsistency between a table
> and an index, then you can use an ANALYZE statement for a thorough
> analysis of the index. Since typically most objects in a database are
> not corrupt, you can use this quick query to eliminate a number of
> tables as candidates for corruption and only use the ANALYZE statement
> on tables that might be corrupt.
>
> To validate an index, run the following query:
>
> ```
> SELECT /*+ FULL(ALIAS) PARALLEL(ALIAS, DOP) */ SUM(ORA_HASH(ROWID))
>    FROM table_name ALIAS 
>    WHERE ALIAS.index_column IS NOT NULL 
>       MINUS SELECT /*+ INDEX_FFS(ALIAS index_name) 
>       PARALLEL_INDEX(ALIAS, index_name, DOP) */ SUM(ORA_HASH(ROWID)) 
>    FROM table_name ALIAS WHERE ALIAS.index_column IS NOT NULL;
> ```
>
> When you run the query, make the following substitutions:
>
> - Enter the table name for the table_name placeholder.
> - Enter the index column for the index_column placeholder.
> - Enter the index name for the index_name placeholder.
>
> If the query returns any rows, then there is a possible inconsistency,
> and you can use an ANALYZE statement for further diagnosis.

If you need in-depth analysis of the index, then the `analyze` command is the only way.

If you're trying to collect optimizer statistics, however, there are alternatives:

> Note:The use of ANALYZE for the collection of optimizer statistics is
> obsolete.
>
> If you want to collect optimizer statistics, use the
> [DBMS_STATS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_STATS.html) package, which lets you collect statistics in parallel,
> global statistics for partitioned objects, and helps you fine tune
> your statistics collection in other ways. See Oracle Database PL/SQL
> Packages and Types Reference for more information on the DBMS_STATS
> package.
>
> Use the ANALYZE statement only for the following cases:
>
> - To use the VALIDATE or LIST CHAINED ROWS clauses
> - To collect information on freelist blocks

See the [Oracle Database SQL Tuning Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/tgsql/gathering-optimizer-statistics.html#GUID-245F23B2-24AF-44D8-9F12-99FD1215E878) to learn how to manage optimizer statistics.

Comment: I've that read analyze command lock the table for dml statements. That is the issue.

Comment: Updated my answer with some info related to the DBMS_STATS package. See if that could meet your needs...

Comment: Oracle does not collect all metadata with `DBMS_STATS` that it does with `ANALYZE`. OP was asking about `ANALYZE INDEX ... VALIDATE STRUCTURE` which loads `INDEX_STATS`. Just like `DBMS_STATS` does not collect data for `DBA_TABLES.CHAIN_CNT` which is collected by running `ANALYZE TABLE`.

Answer (score 1):

With up to date table statistics, you can use [DBMS_SPACE.CREATE_INDEX_COST](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/arpls/DBMS_SPACE.html#GUID-B6EB7527-BC67-4394-9E7A-01F2790C409A) to find the estimated size of an index if you were to create it, then you can compare it with the actual size to see if there is significant difference.

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17679033/how-to-tell-the-amount-of-tablespace-that-would-be-freed-by-rebuilding-indexes

Another example: https://carlos-sierra.net/2017/07/12/script-to-identify-index-rebuild-candidates-on-12c/

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--
-- File name: indexes_2b_shrunk.sql
--
-- Purpose: List of candidate indexes to be shrunk (rebuild online)
--
-- Author: Carlos Sierra
--
-- Version: 2017/07/12
--
-- Usage: Execute on PDB
--
-- Example: @indexes_2b_shrunk.sql
--
-- Notes: Execute connected into a PDB.
-- Consider then:
-- ALTER INDEX [schema.]index REBUILD ONLINE;
--
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
-- select only those indexes with an estimated space saving percent greater than 25%
VAR savings_percent NUMBER;
EXEC :savings_percent := 25;
-- select only indexes with current size (as per cbo stats) greater then 1MB
VAR minimum_size_mb NUMBER;
EXEC :minimum_size_mb := 1;
 
SET SERVEROUT ON ECHO OFF FEED OFF VER OFF TAB OFF LINES 300;
 
COL report_date NEW_V report_date;
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') report_date FROM DUAL;
SPO /tmp/indexes_2b_shrunk_&&report_date..txt;
 
DECLARE
l_used_bytes NUMBER;
l_alloc_bytes NUMBER;
l_percent NUMBER;
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PDB: '||SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'CON_NAME'));
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('---');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
RPAD('OWNER.INDEX_NAME', 35)||' '||
LPAD('SAVING %', 10)||' '||
LPAD('CURRENT SIZE', 20)||' '||
LPAD('ESTIMATED SIZE', 20));
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
RPAD('-', 35, '-')||' '||
LPAD('-', 10, '-')||' '||
LPAD('-', 20, '-')||' '||
LPAD('-', 20, '-'));
FOR i IN (SELECT x.owner, x.index_name, SUM(s.leaf_blocks) * TO_NUMBER(p.value) index_size,
REPLACE(DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('INDEX',x.index_name,x.owner),CHR(10),CHR(32)) ddl
FROM dba_ind_statistics s, dba_indexes x, dba_users u, v$parameter p
WHERE u.oracle_maintained = 'N'
AND x.owner = u.username
AND x.tablespace_name NOT IN ('SYSTEM','SYSAUX')
AND x.index_type LIKE '%NORMAL%'
AND x.table_type = 'TABLE'
AND x.status = 'VALID'
AND x.temporary = 'N'
AND x.dropped = 'NO'
AND x.visibility = 'VISIBLE'
AND x.segment_created = 'YES'
AND x.orphaned_entries = 'NO'
AND p.name = 'db_block_size'
AND s.owner = x.owner
AND s.index_name = x.index_name
GROUP BY
x.owner, x.index_name, p.value
HAVING
SUM(s.leaf_blocks) * TO_NUMBER(p.value) > :minimum_size_mb * POWER(2,20)
ORDER BY
index_size DESC)
LOOP
DBMS_SPACE.CREATE_INDEX_COST(i.ddl,l_used_bytes,l_alloc_bytes);
IF i.index_size * (100 - :savings_percent) / 100 > l_alloc_bytes THEN
l_percent := 100 * (i.index_size - l_alloc_bytes) / i.index_size;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
RPAD(i.owner||'.'||i.index_name, 35)||' '||
LPAD(TO_CHAR(ROUND(l_percent, 1), '990.0')||' % ', 10)||' '||
LPAD(TO_CHAR(ROUND(i.index_size / POWER(2,20), 1), '999,999,990.0')||' MB', 20)||' '||
LPAD(TO_CHAR(ROUND(l_alloc_bytes / POWER(2,20), 1), '999,999,990.0')||' MB', 20));
END IF;
END LOOP;
END;
/
 
SPO OFF;
```

This will not give you the actual ratio of deleted rows as `ANALYZE INDEX ... VALIDATE STRUCTURE` does in `INDEX_STATS`, just an estimation, but that may be good enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

The term *fragmentation* is quite vague to me - so I just hope my suggestion helps answering your question:

In a recent [blogpost](https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2022/09/02/shrinking-indexes/) Jonathan Lewis used this query to generate a histogram of index blocks with their containing rows:

```
select
        rows_per_block,
        count(*)        block_count
from    (
        select
                /*+
                        dynamic_sampling(0)
                        index_ffs(t1,t1_i1)
                        noparallel_index(t,t1_i1)
                */
                sys_op_lbid( &m_ind_id ,'L',t1.rowid)   as block_id,
                count(*)                                as rows_per_block
        from
                t1
        group by
                sys_op_lbid( &m_ind_id ,'L',t1.rowid)
        )
group by
        rows_per_block
order by
        rows_per_block
;
```

This gives you some informetion how (un-)even the data is distributed in your index' leafe blocks.

If you are more concerned about the *clustering factor* - there is a series of [blogposts](https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2019/10/23/clustering_factor-7/) by Jonathan which explain it in very good detail.